# why the VTypes I defined will be triggered three times?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to check if the content of a textfield has exist in the database,so I define a VTypes:

```
Ext.apply( Ext.form.field.VTypes,{
sampleSetExist: function(val, field) {
    alert('triggered');
    var result;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'sampleSetExist.action',
        params: {
                name:val
        },
        async:false,
        success: function(response){
            var res = response.responseText;
            var jsonObject = Ext.decode( res );
            if( jsonObject.exist == true )
                result = false;
            else 
                result = true;
        }
        });
        return result;
    }
});
```

and the textfield like this:

```
{
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    itemId: 'sampleSetName',
    name: 'ssi.name',
    allowBlank: false,
    validateOnBlur: true,
    validateOnChange: false,
    vtype: 'sampleSetExist',
    vtypeText: 'The name has exist!'
}
……
```

when the textfield blur,the validator function sampleSetExist will be triggered for three times.Why will this happen?

Comment: please create example on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in another answer, the `vtype` config (and also the `validator` function) should be used for quick local, synchronous validation (like making sure a date range end is after a date range start).

A better way to do this sort of remote validation would be the field `change` event to do the work. You could save an Ajax request to the field and use it to do your own validation. This should accomplish what you're trying to do on the client side, but remember that users can perform their own form submission. Make sure you re-validate the submitted values when they reaches your server.

In addition to the code below, you would probably want extra validation at submission time to make sure the user hasn't tried to submit the form before a validation request finished.

Note: This might not be the *best* way, but it should point you in the right direction.

```
// Field config
{
    fieldLabel: "Name",
    checkChangeBuffer: 500,  // How long to wait after last change event
    listeners: {
        change: MyApp.onNameFieldChange
    },
    // Rest of config here
}

// "MyApp" is whatever namespace you're using for this form
MyApp.onNameFieldChange = function(field, newValue) {
    var request = field.validationXhr;

    // Cancel any existing requests
    if (request) {
        Ext.Ajax.abort(request);
    }

    // Send your params for validation
    field.validationXhr = Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: "sampleSetExist.action",
        /* params, timeout, etc. */

        success: function(response) {
            var jsonResponse = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            if (jsonResponse.exist) {
                // markInvalid only displays an error message. It doesn't actually
                // set the field state to invalid. Extra logic may be needed.
                field.markInvalid("The name " + newValue + " already exists!");
            }
            else {
                field.clearInvalid();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not worry about it being invoked three times. VTypes are not designed for things requiring asking the server. This kind of validations should be performed upon form submission. VTypes suppose to return true or false and are only intended for field or record validation.